# Protractor - Drop down Element Not Visible(auto complete drop down)

Tags: angularjs, automation, protractor

I have been facing different diff kind of element not visible issues in my application. kindly help me for solution on this.

below or the html code

**For Drop Down**

```
<span class="btn btn-default form-control ui-select-toggle" style="outline: 0;" ng-click="$select.activate()" ng-disabled="$select.disabled" aria-label="Select box activate" tabindex="-1">
```

**To Type text in the Auto Complete Drop down.**

```
<span class="ui-select-placeholder text-muted ng-binding" ng-show="$select.isEmpty()">Select Reseller...</span>
```

I was able to click on the drop down and enter the text. but after that it fails with element not visible error

Comment: I tried the below fix but it doesnt work

 this.ResellerName = element(by.css('.btn.btn-default.form-control.ui-select-toggle'));
        this.ResellerName1 =element(by.css('input[ng-model="$select.search"]'));

AdSell.ResellerName.click();
            browser.sleep(2000);
            AdSell.ResellerName1.sendKeys(Data.ResellerName);
            browser.sleep(2000);
         browser.actions().sendKeys( protractor.Key.ENTER ).perform();
         browser.sleep(2000);

Comment: There is no repeater on the drop down values r else i could have selected by text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If u can click on the Auto complete drop down then try to select the drop down by text value.

```
by.linkText('Text to be selected'));
```

or

try using the below function (this will select the value by text)

```
this.SelectRowByCellValue = function (Elem, Texts)
{

        Elem.filter(function (element) {
        return element.getText().then(function (text) {
            if (text == Texts && text != null)
            {
                element.click();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        });
    }).then(function (filteredElements) {

    });
};
```